# Entity Framework vs. AssociateWith

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

When I use Linq2Sql I can filter a table by using a lambda-expression in the DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith method.

I use this for filtering the used language - so I have a language table with all languages and a object table containing objects.

Like:

```
DataLoadOptions opt = ...;
opt.AssociateWith<DB.Objects>(o => o.Language.Where(p => p.Culture == CurrentUser.Culture));
```

How to do that with the entity-framework - where I have to use .Include(string) instead of the dataloadoptions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please let us know which version of EF you are using.

But saying that you want to use the "include" method, then it would probably look like this.

```
var result = dbContext.Objects.Include("Language").Where(p=>p.Culture == CurrentUser.Culture );
```

note that "Language" should reflect what is set in your navigation property name in your model. (so watch out for plurals)