# Alternative for Linq 2 Sql AssociateWith method

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I am rewriting ASP.NET MVC application to ASP.NET CORE and have came accross with a case using Linq 2 Sql AssociateWith method for which I am not sure how to rewrite it properly. In .NET Core I am now using Entity framework.

Linq 2 Sql code:

```
var option = new System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions();
option.LoadWith<Device>(e => e.SensorStatus);
option.LoadWith<Device>(e => e.SensorVisibilities);
option.AssociateWith<Device>(e => e.SensorStatus.OrderByDescending(c => c.SensorDataID).Take(1));
option.LoadWith<SensorStatus>(e => e.SensorDatas);
ctx.LoadOptions = option;
```

Current EF code, for which I am not sure if I got it right:

```
var devices = ctx.Device.Include(x => x.SensorStatus)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.SensorData).OrderByDescending(x => x.SensorStatus.Select(y => y.SensorDataId)).Take(1)
                        .Include(x => x.SensorVisibility);
```

ps. I've searched posts on Stack but found only one similar topic, where there was just one join. ([Entity Framework vs. AssociateWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609973/entity-framework-vs-associatewith))

Comment: Entity Framework using *LINQ to Entities": is that what you mean? (LINQ to SQL was from the older, pre-EF, >NET LINQ ORM.)

Comment: @Richard No, it's actually linq-to-sql: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888818/linq-to-sql-loadwith-vs-associatewith

Comment: Second read: I see what you mean. Perhaps "Rewriting LINQ to SQL's AssociateWith in EF Core" might have been clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option in Entity Framework to filter what you are loading when you use `.Include()`.
The calls to `.OrderByDescending().Take()` in your query is affecting how the `Device`s are loaded, not `SensorStatus.SensorData`.

You have two options:

1. Load everything as you are doing, but leave aside the calls to `OrderByDescending().Take()` as that's not what you want:

   ```
   var devices = ctx.Device
       .Include(x => x.SensorStatus)
           .ThenInclude(x => x.SensorData)
       .Include(x => x.SensorVisibility);
   ```
2. Load up to `SensorStatus` and choose what to load afterwards:

   ```
   var devices = ctx.Device
       .Include(x => x.SensorStatus)
       .Include(x => x.SensorVisibility);

   foreach (var device in devices)
   {
       device.SensorStatus.SensorData = ctx.SensorStatus
           .Where(x => x.SensorStatusId == device.SensorStatusId) // I'm assuming the name of the key here
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.SensorDataId)
           .FirstOrDefault();
   }
   ```